# Duplicate indentation of current line

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, indentation

Some console editors distinguish between "inserting a newline" and "inserting a newline + matching the level of indentation of the current line".

For instance, the editor `mg` distinguishes between `C-j` (which matches the previous level of indentation) and `C-m` (which just inserts a `\n`) in C mode.

GNU Emacs (which `mg` is emulating) does more sophisticated stuff to determine the appropriate level of indentation, but I like the simple "just use the indentation level of the previous line" of mg.

If the buffer consists of (where `.` is space)

```
.....a
```

Then hitting `C-j` will do...

```
.....a
.....
```

I was wondering if there's a way (particularly a built-in way) to get the same indentation-matching behavior in vim when I hit `C-j`.

I have a utility function for extracting whitespace characters from the beginning of a numbered line, but I can't figure out how to package it into a command that grabs the corresponding characters from the current line, inserts a newline, and then inserts the whitespace prefix from the original line.

```
function! GetIndentationPrefix(linum)
    let line = getline(a:linum)
    let index = 0
    let target = strlen(line)
    let whitespace_prefix = ''
    while index <# target
        if line[index] ==# ' '
            let whitespace_prefix = whitespace_prefix . ' '
        elseif line[index] ==# '\t'
            let whitespace_prefix = whitespace_prefix . '\t'
        else
            break
        endif
        let index = index + 1
    endwhile
    return whitespace_prefix
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `set cindent` or `set autoindent`, vim actually does match indent when you press `<c-j>`.  But it also does when you press `<cr>`. To circumvent this you could make a mapping like:

`inoremap <cr> <cr><c-o>i`

So now `<c-j>` will match indent, but `<cr>` won't.

Answer (score 1):

If you `set ai`, then `<c-j>` (in insert mode) will do what you want.
If you want the Enter-Key to behave differently then you also can
`:inoremap <cr> <cr>0<c-d>`